# Найти точку пересечения графиков прямой и окружности по заданным координатам

Tags: разработка-игр, математика, график

Даны координаты точки M и O, как найти A? Ясно, что надо найти эту точку через пересечения графика прямой  и окружности. Но я не могу правильно сократить уравнения. Возможно ли это вообще и есть ли другие решения?

ps, кто знает подкиньте сайт со шпаргалками по мат.формулам для gamedev'a[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сформулируйте нормально задачу. Не "хочу красиво", а - что задано, что найти... Например, если заданы O и M, и надо найти A - то как минимум не хватает радиуса окружности.

Comment: Сайт со шпаргалками - справочник по аналитической геометрии.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте так, что пункт `O` будет в начале:

```
O'(0, 0)
```

Тогда

```
M'(x1-x0, y1-y0)
A'(x -x0, y -y0)
```

Пусть `r` радиус окружности. Тогда отношения

```
(x - x0) / (x1 - x0)
(y - y0) / (y1 - y0)
|OA| / |OM|
```

будут равняться друг другу. Последнее отношение вычислит просто, так как `|OA| = r`. Затем из первых двух вычислите `x`, `y`.